# Strange icon in my menu bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar

This strange icon decided to appear in my menubar this week, and I have absolutely no clue as to what it is. Could anyone help with this?

What steps should I take to finding out what process that owns this icon?

[image: strange icon]

The icon doesn't interact with any single, double or right clicks, and does not drag out with a command+drag.

It comes and goes, but recently it decided to stay a bit longer. I'm a bit concerned, because I don't recall installing any new apps.

Comment: No idea, but it looks like something Git/VC related with that branch symbol.

Comment: Try looking in Activity Monitor for unknown apps.

Comment: Any thing in preferences for your login items?  Someone asked here about the same icon many months ago.  I don't remember the answer.

Comment: looks like the git symbol in visual studio code, do you have that installed?

Comment: thank you for this question! I just googled for "git icon in my menu bar" and this was the last hit on the first page. And it was indeed Libre Office in the background asking to upgrade itself. A++ would buy again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the same thing just now, it's the Libre Office update icon but sad it's not responding on 1 click...

Comment: Thanks! LibreOffice did remind me that there was an update. Just updated now and the icon doesn't seem to appear. Too bad Libreoffice can't support auto updates just yet...

Comment: Clicking it will pop up the "Check for Updates" dialog if it's not already open, but it won't raise the dialog to the top if it's hanging out in the background.