# Which app does this menu bar icon belong to?

Tags: menu-bar

[image: 1]]

I'm talking about the leftmost icon in the bar, to the left of the f.lux icon. Nothing happens when I click on it. And having opened the menu on another item and then navigating to the left or right with arrow keys, will jump over this item.

Comment: Linked (maybe a duplicate): [How to identify application of hung menu bar icon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143634/how-to-identify-application-of-hung-menu-bar-icon) - Xcode required!

Comment: @klanomath No BitBar or anything like this installed.

Comment: I can see you tried clicking on it, have you tried using option, control, shift or command click in various combinations, many applications have hidden or secondary menus.

Comment: @unknowndomain After restart (due to update) the icon has disappeared. The icon didn't resemble any icon of my installed apps.

Comment: Sure but any application can put anything it wants up there it doesn't have to be the application icon, the fact it is on the left suggests it is an application not a menu bar extra from the OS or similar. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 1):

It's a stupid LibreOffice icon showing up when a new update is existing.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/252910/361005