# Does anyone know what third-party app uses this menubar icon?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, third-party

This icon appeared on the right side of my menu bar; it had no name or dropdown menu when I moused over it or selected it.

[image: macOS menu bar icon consisting of a vertical line with diagonal line running NW to SE and down arrow in SE corner1]

I researched Apple documentation and believe it's something I installed and not part of the OS.

Does anyone recognize this or know how to sort out which app injects an icon into the menu bar?

Comment: Not a gamer, so I’m not sure, but that looks like the Steam icon.  You can also confirm if it’s an Apple system icon by booting into Safe Mode. If it goes away, it’s not Apple’s icon.

Comment: @Allan Steam's icon is about the same but flipped

Comment: Thanks, I don't have steam installed on this machine--but I agree, it looks like that. 
 The icon was only temporary--it disappeared after I managed to get a screenshot.

Comment: Answer: This is a newer version of the LibreOffice background updater.  [The old icon was a down arrow over a globe.] See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252790/strange-icon-in-my-menu-bar